# Is there "If exists" parameter in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess

I can have urls of three types, which should rewrite to:

```
http://example.com/admin      -> http://example.com/admin.php
http://example.com/admin/2    -> http://example.com/admin.php?cat=2
http://example.com/admin/2/2  -> http://example.com/admin.php?cat=2&page=2
```

Also, .php should be added to ALL the .php files in the project.

I have this rules right now:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^admin/(\d+)/(\d+)$ admin.php?cat=$1&page=$2
```

And I don't know how to make this work properly. I need to make the second rule about page parameter to be situational, only when it exists, because otherwise .htaccess tries to rewrite only the whole line with page number in it.

Any help? Thanks for attention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^admin/(\d+)/?$ admin.php?cat=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^admin/(\d+)/(\d+)$ admin.php?cat=$1&page=$2 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: But one comment to this: after I removed that `/` in the last line it became perfect. Thank you.